# Underline part of label in DOT (graphviz)

Tags: html, graphviz, class-diagram, dot

I want to create my class diagram with DOT and therefore I need to underline the static methods.

Currently my source is:

```
digraph G {                                                                
    fontname = "Bitstream Vera Sans"                                       
    fontsize = 8                                                           

    node [                                                                 
        fontname = "Bitstream Vera Sans"                                   
        fontsize = 10                                                      
        shape = "record"                                                   
    ]                                                                      

    edge [                                                                 
        fontname = "Bitstream Vera Sans"                                   
        fontsize = 10                                                      
    ]                                                                      

    subgraph packagemodel {                                                

        Class [                                                            
            label = "{Classname|\l\                                        
                + attribute|\l\                                            
                + staticfunction}"                                         
        ]                                                                  
    }                                                                      
}
```

but I did not find out how to make a part of a label underlined. Do you know that could be made?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

I now changed it to:

```
digraph G {                                                                
    fontname = "Bitstream Vera Sans"                                       
    fontsize = 8                                                           

    node [                                                                 
        fontname = "Bitstream Vera Sans"                                   
        fontsize = 10                                                      
        shape = "record"                                                   
    ]                                                                      

    edge [                                                                 
        fontname = "Bitstream Vera Sans"                                   
        fontsize = 10                                                      
    ]                                                                      

    subgraph packagemodel {                                                

        Class [
            label =
            <<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellborder="1">             
            <tr>                                                       
                <td>Sudoku3DFactory</td>                               
            </tr>                                                      
            <tr>                                                       
                <td>attribute</td>                                              
            </tr>                                                      
            <tr>                                                       
                <td><u>+ staticfunction</u></td>  
            </tr>                                                      
            </table>>
        ]
    }
}
```

but it is still not underlined.

Comment: In this case, don't use records, use [HTML-like labels](http://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#html)

Comment: changed shape to none, but that did not help

Comment: Which command do you use for compiling? The code in my answer in a file `so.dot`, compiled with `dot -T png -o so.png so.dot` creates the underline.

Comment: I use `dot -T svg -o so.svg so.dot`

Comment: That also produces the underline on my system, as it should. Sorry I'm out of my depth here. Maybe a matter of OS or version. Maybe you add your OS info and graphviz version number to your post, although I would not be able to comment.

Comment: I agree, I tried it on another computer and there it worked, so thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  need to change from `shape = record` to `shape = plain`. On some systems, this shape is not available, on mine for example, then this helps:

```
digraph G {                                                                
    fontname = "Bitstream Vera Sans"                                       
    fontsize = 8                                                           

    node [                                                                 
        fontname = "Bitstream Vera Sans"                                   
        fontsize = 10                                                      
        shape = none width=0 height=0 margin=0   // this _is_ plain                               
    ]                                                                      

    edge [                                                                 
        fontname = "Bitstream Vera Sans"                                   
        fontsize = 10                                                      
    ]                                                                      

    subgraph packagemodel {                                                

        Class [
            label =
            <<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellborder="1">             
            <tr>                                                       
                <td>Sudoku3DFactory</td>                               
            </tr>                                                      
            <tr>                                                       
                <td>attribute</td>                                              
            </tr>                                                      
            <tr>                                                       
                <td><u>+ staticfunction</u></td>  
            </tr>                                                      
            </table>>
        ]
    }
}
```

This produces

[image]

including the underline.

Comment: thanks, even if it abnormally not working on both of my systems, but one